# How to sort Tumblr posts by tag without changing page?

Tags: sorting, tags, themes, tumblr

I tried this code:

```
{block:Posts}
<ul>
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}
<a href="{TagURL}"><li>{Tag}</li></a>
{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
</ul>
{/block:Posts}
```

However when you click one it takes you to another page. How can I make this sort them without going to another page?

Example of the sorting I want to achieve: http://purifytheme.tumblr.com/

Comment: @mikedidthis, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm going to say using `{TagsAsClasses}` and javascript to turn on and off a `display: none` class attribute depending on what you click. I'm not going to write out an entire solution because well, that would take longer than I'm willing to commit, right now, but this should help give you a starting point.

Comment: @Minedeep that particular theme uses `isotope.js` to handle the filtering: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/